# How to get new token headers during runtime of scrapy spider

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-middleware

I am running a scrapy spider that starts by getting an authorization token from the website I am scraping from, using basic requests library. The function for this is called get_security_token(). This token is passed as a header to the scrapy request. The issue is that the token expires after 300 seconds, and then I get a 401 error. Is there anyway for a spider to see the 401 error, run the get_security_token() function again, and then pass the new token on to all future request headers?

```
import scrapy

class PlayerSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'player'

def start_requests(self):

    urls = ['URL GOES HERE']
    header_data = {'Authorization':'Bearer 72bb65d7-2ff1-3686-837c-61613454928d'}
    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url = url, callback = self.parse,headers = header_data)


def parse(self, response):
    yield response.json()
```

Answer (score 1):

if it's pure scrapy you can add `handle_httpstatus_list = [501]` after `start_urls`
and then in you `parse` method you need to do something like this:

```py
if response.status == 501:
    get_security_token()
```

Comment: How would I get that new security token to be passed into all future requests, as well as the one that threw the error?

Comment: once you get token ```get_security_token()```, you can pass those headers into request ```yield scrapy.Request(url=your_url, headers=headers_with_new_token, callback=self.your_callback)```.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. My only question is - the `headers_with_new_token` will be sent in the `scrapy.Request` call within the `parse` method, but how can I make sure that all requests after that also use the `headers_with_new_token`?

Comment: you can check ```response.headers``` for requests with the updated token

Comment: I've added some code to illustrate where I'm at. The issue is the 'Authorization':'Bearer xxx' key expires. Maybe with my code you could better describe where I should put that variable so I can change it in runtime?

Comment: something like this ```def parse(self, response):
        print(response.request.headers['Authorization'])
        if response.status == 501:
            header_data = get_security_token()
            yield scrapy.Request(url=response.url, callback=self.parse, headers=header_data, dont_filter=True)```